# Jester and a Monarch

Tags: riddle, word

A jester comes to court one day and entertains the crowd. At one point he makes a remark that reflects poorly of the monarch's intelligence. To preserve his dignity, the monarch challenges the jester to riddle him.

A riddle goes in the following manner

> The one who barely didn't medal
>   The one after that
>   The under 18 collapse
>   The lieutenant colonel's subordinate's elevator

What should the confused monarch proclaim?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The king should proclaim:

> HALLELUJAH

Meanings of the lines of the riddle are:

The one who barely didn't medal

> The fourth

The one after that

> The fifth

The under 18 collapse

> The minor fall

The lieutenant colonel's subordinate's elevator

> The major's lift

Which put together form (almost precisely):

> Part of the first stanza of the song "Hallelujah" by Leonard Cohen, which also continues with *The baffled king composing hallelujah* (hence the confused monarch)

Comment: Nice :)$ $$ $$ $